# Kivy accessing class attributes from screen manager

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using python and kivy to make a simple app, but when I create multiple screen for my app, I cannot access the class attributes of some class.

I have problem accessing a method using screen manager.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def print_a_word(self):
        print('a word')

class OptionWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('screen_manager.kv')

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**kivy file (screen_manager.kv)**

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
# File name: screen_manager.kv
#: import MyGame Widget

WindowManager:

    OptionWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<OptionWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0, 0
                size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            rows: 5
            padding: 50, 50
            spacing: 20, 20
            OptionBtn:
                text: 'Americas'
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"



<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    MyGame
    Button:
        on_press: root.MyGame.print_a_word()


<OptionBtn@Button>
    background_normal: 'Images/Other/white.png'
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: 20
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.size[0], self.size[1]
```

Everything works well until I press on the button of the second window. I cannot access the method from MyGame(Widget). I get`'SecondWindow' object has no attribute 'MyGame'`

This is part of a bigger issue because I made this file to solve my original issue which is...
I have a big program in which I have two files main.py and my.kv and I want to add screens. In this main.py, everything is defined a class that inherits from Widget and the build method returns an instance of that class. This is why I made the files from above... it is to understand how I can access from the Widget class. Thank you

Comment: Please stay focused on your question. There's no need to advertise that you're learning. That's understood and encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I fixed your example code now the print_my_word() method inside MyGame() object can be accessed and executed this should be enough to get you in the way.

Only the kv file needed change:

Used include instead of import in "MyGame" object:
#: include MyGame

Instantiate it inside <SecondWindow> object.

Added an id to it, to be able to access it.

```
WindowManager:

    OptionWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<OptionWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0, 0
                size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            rows: 5
            padding: 50, 50
            spacing: 20, 20
            OptionBtn:
                text: 'Americas'
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"



<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    MyGame:
        id: my_game
    Button:
        on_press: my_game.print_a_word()


<OptionBtn@Button>
    background_normal: 'Images/Other/white.png'
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: 20
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.size[0], self.size[1]
```

**Ok this next part below is an update to respond your question in the second comment.**

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def print_a_word(self):
        print('My Game: print method')

class OptionWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('screen_manager.kv')

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.my_game = MyGame()  # <-- instantiated MyGame in the Main class to access it from any where
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

screen_manager.kv

```
WindowManager:
    OptionWindow:
    SecondWindow:



<OptionWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0, 0
                size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            rows: 5
            padding: 50, 50
            spacing: 20, 20
            OptionBtn:
                text: 'Americas'
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            # ADDED EXTRA BUTTON TO SAMPLE ACCESSING MyGame OBJECT, FROM THIS CLASS
            Button:
                text: 'Access My Game Method'
                on_release:
                    app.my_game.print_a_word()   # <-- app can access main class attributes and methods



<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    # USE A BOXLAYOUT TO LAYOUT THE BUTTONS
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 2
        padding: 2
        # ADDED BUTTON TO SAMPLE ACCESSING MyGame OBJECT
        Button:
            text: 'Access method from MyGame'
            on_press: app.my_game.print_a_word()     # <-- app can access main class attributes and methods
        Button:
            text: 'Return to Main'
            on_press: app.root.current = "main"



<OptionBtn@Button>
    background_normal: 'Images/Other/white.png'
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: 20
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.size[0], self.size[1]
```

Comment: by any chance, do you know how I could access my_game.print_a_word() from another class, say <OptionWindow> ? I have tried all sort of things such as   app.root.second.my_game.print_a_word(), but in vain. I am starting to understand thanks to you

Comment: I updated my response to answer your previous comment, I hope this helps.